# Paginated data cursor in RXJS and confusion about subject.onCompleted and errors

Tags: javascript, pagination, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm working with RXJS and came up with an implementation of a paginated data cursor. Having not spent too much time with reactive functional programming, I'm wondering if my implementation is in the spirit of how this library is intended to be used.

I want a class that can load in pages from an endpoint. If you subscribe to it, you will receive the last page that was queried. The first subscription results in the first page being automatically queried. A call to "getPage" should trigger an onNext for all subscriptions. Multiple subscriptions should NOT cause multiple requests.

I wrote a basic example that satisfies this, heavily commented with my thought process: https://jsfiddle.net/gfmn708g/1/

My questions are:

- Is this in the spirit of RXJS? Using both a ReplySubject and shareReplay feels wrong to me, but I found no other way to get the behavior that I want. I read that using Subjects is "bad" and against the principles of the paradigm.
- Will line 63 unsubscribe/finish all of the items$ subscriptions (lines 82 and 89) AFTER all in-flight requests are completed and processed?
- What is the proper way to handle errors, so that errors are propagated to the subscribers, but they don't murder the stream and prevent me from pushing any more requests?

(Here's a listing of the code per SO's question guidelines)

```
const logDiv = $("#log");
function log(message, cls) {
    logDiv.append($("<li>").text(message).addClass(cls));
}

/* interface IRequest {
    url: string;
    page: number:
    refresh?: boolean
}

interface IEndpoint {
    get(request: IRequest): [];
} */

// Class that represents a cursor into paginated data
function PagedData(endpoint, url) {
    this._endpoint = endpoint;
    this._url = url;

    // Our request queue is an observable of structurs of type IRequest
    // We use a reply subject so that the last URL requested is in the stream when the first subscriber subscribes.
    this._requestQueue = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);

    // This is our data observable, subscribe to it to
    // A) receive the last page that this cursor has produced
    // B) receive all future pages
    this.items$ = this._requestQueue
        // Don't re-query unless the "refresh" boolean is true
        .distinctUntilChanged(req => req, (left, right) => right.refresh ? false : left.page == right.page)
        // Make the request...
        .flatMapLatest(request => Rx.Observable.of(request).zip(this._endpoint.get(request)))
        // Wrap data returned with an envelope with data such as which page was requested
        .map(data => {
            const request = data[0];
            const response = data[1];
            return {
                page: request.page,
                url: request.url,
                items: response
            };              
        })
        // Replay last page worth of data on each subscription
        .shareReplay(1);

    // Queue up the first page to be retrieved on first subscription
    this.getPage(1);
}

PagedData.prototype.getPage = function(page, refresh) {
    refresh = refresh || false;

    // Fire off the workflow
    this._requestQueue.onNext({
        url: this._url,
        refresh: refresh,
        page: page
    });
}

PagedData.prototype.dispose = function() {
    // Question: this should unsubscribe ALL of the subscriptions to this.items$, right?
    this._requestQueue.completed();
}

// -----------------
// EXAMPLE USAGE

var dummyEndpoint = {
    get(request) {
        log(`GET: ${request.url} at page ${request.page}`, "service");
        return Rx.Observable.range(request.page * 10, 10)
            .delay(1000)
            .map(i => ({id: i, title: `Track ${i}`}))
            .toArray();
    }
};

const tracks = new PagedData(dummyEndpoint, "/api/tracks");

// This results in getting the first page
tracks.items$.subscribe(data => {
    log(`On page ${data.page}, ${data.items.map(i => i.title).join(",")}`, "first")
});

// Wait one second after getting the first page
window.setTimeout(() => {
    // Subscribe again, we will receive the first page with no re-query
    tracks.items$.subscribe(data => log(`Got page ${data.page} after delay`, "second"));

    // Get the second page
    tracks.getPage(2);

    // Wait another second after getting the second page
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        log("Getting second page (without refresh)");
        // This shouldn't result in anything, since "refresh" is false/undefined
        tracks.getPage(2);

        // Wait one more second...
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            log("Getting second page (with refresh)");
            // This should result in getting the second page, refresh is true
            tracks.getPage(2, true);

      // Should get rid of all subscriptions after the last in-flight request?
            tracks.dispose();
        }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't so much that `Subjects` are bad as they tend to be crutch for new users so they don't have to actually use the paradigm (an Observable and Observer for the price of one, how can I afford *not* to use it?).

In all seriousness though I think your gut on this is correct, the use of a `ReplaySubject` + `shareReplay` is a code smell. What might help is to try think where your data is *actually* coming from. In most cases functions don't exist just by themselves, they are actually triggered by something else.

You need to find what that something else is and follow it until you find the root source. In most cases this source will be a user or network event that you can wrap using `fromEvent` or `fromPromise`. Once you have that starting point it is just a matter of connecting that source to what you want to do.

So I would refactor your business logic of calling the endpoint into a `Observable` extension:

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.paginate = function(endpoint, url) {

  return this
    .startWith({
      page: 1,
      refresh: false
    })
    .map(req => 
      ({page: req.page,url: url,refresh: req.refresh}))
    .distinctUntilChanged(req => req,
      (left, right) => right.refresh ? false :
      left.page == right.page)
    .flatMapLatest(request => endpoint.get(request),
      (request, response) => ({
        page: request.page,
        url: request.url,
        items: response
      }))
    .shareReplay(1)
}
```

The above will wait for the first subscription and then automatically make the first request when that subscription occurs. After that each subsequent subscriber will receive the latest value from the pagination.

From there it will depend on your source but I would imagine you would probably do something like:

```
var trigger = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($nextPageButton, 'click')
  .scan((current, _) => current + 1, 1)
  .paginate(endpoint, url);


trigger.subscribe(/*Handle result*/);
```

In this case you likely wouldn't unsubscribe until your page needed to unload, instead you would just hook up your pipeline on load and it would take care of the rest. All the while subscribing to `trigger` would always get you the latest data.

I added a working sample using a refactoring of your existing code.

```js
const logDiv = $("#log");

function log(message, cls) {
  logDiv.append($("<li>").text(message).addClass(cls));
}

/* interface IRequest {
 url: string;
 page: number:
 refresh?: boolean
}

interface IEndpoint {
 get(request: IRequest): [];
} */


Rx.Observable.prototype.paginate = function(endpoint, url) {

  return this
    .startWith({
      page: 1,
      refresh: false
    })
    .map(req => 
      ({page: req.page,url: url,refresh: req.refresh}))
    .distinctUntilChanged(req => req,
      (left, right) => right.refresh ? false :
      left.page == right.page)
    .flatMapLatest(request => endpoint.get(request),
      (request, response) => ({
        page: request.page,
        url: request.url,
        items: response
      }))
    .shareReplay(1)
}

// -----------------
// EXAMPLE USAGE

var dummyEndpoint = {
  get(request) {
    log(`GET: ${request.url} at page ${request.page} with${request.refresh ? "" : "out"} refresh`, "service");
    return Rx.Observable.range(request.page * 10, 10)
      .delay(1000)
      .map(i => ({
        id: i,
        title: `Track ${i}`
      }))
      .toArray();
  }
};

var trigger = Rx.Observable.concat(
  Rx.Observable.just({
    page: 2
  }).delay(2000),
  Rx.Observable.just({
    page: 2
  }).delay(2000),
  Rx.Observable.just({
    page: 2,
    refresh: true
  }).delay(1000)
);

const tracks = trigger.paginate(dummyEndpoint, "/api/tracks");

tracks.delaySubscription(2000).subscribe(data => log(`Got page ${data.page} after delay`, "second"));

// This results in getting the first page
tracks.subscribe(data => {
  log(`On page ${data.page}, ${data.items.map(i => i.title).join(",")}`, "first")
});
```

```css
#log li.first {
  color: green;
}

#log li.second {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.js"></script>
<ol id="log">
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems a lot simpler. My new code is now: https://jsfiddle.net/1daxw44r/1/ (can't wait for the :: operator...). Anyhow, it seems it'll take a while for me to stop thinking in terms of OO all the time.

So a few more questions... What about errors, and also what if I wanted to "next/prev" buttons to only get the next/prev page of the *last* page that was successfully returned? So that spamming "next" doesn't increment the page counter until the endpoint returns. Also, what if the "next" button depended on a token from the requested page, such as reddit's API?

Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. Wow those might be difficult to answer in the comment section. So I'll give you some operators to look at and if you run into issue come back and ask another question (it'll be more helpful to other users who run into this issue as well). In order of the questions: catch/retryWhen, flatMapFirst/switchFirst, and withLatestFrom. Cheers!